# bootable win xp sp3 usb drive from files on HD

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb

On hard disk I have setup files for win xp xp3. Files are copied from setup CD, but now CD/DVD device is off.
I need to create a bootable usb drive from this files, and tried various programs like WinToFlash, nlite, rufus, ImgBurn... without success. Some programs need original CD, some need bootable iso file, some can handle only win 7/8 setup...

Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Any solution I know of requires the original media.  Its not even clear if the "setup files" you have the required data to make it bootable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to first create iso from WinRar then you can create bootable image on USB device by 3rd party tool.

You can create iso file from WinRar application.

Comment: user230... I have WinRar 4.01 and there is no option to create `iso` file. Only `.rar` and `.zip` are available.

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_6889855_make-iso-winrar.html use this link to create ISO by WinRar